# Filter on first two characters of user input and retrieve from external database any matches of words beginning with the filtered input

Tags: javascript, dynamic, filtering, dropdown

I need to load a pick list from the first two characters of user input filtered on beginning of a word match (as opposed to anywhere in a word) from an external database table.

I am using Bootstrap 4.0 for the page controls and ASP.NET 4.6 framework/C# back end code.  I'm not real familiar with Javascript, but if that is the best way to handle this (performance wise on the table query of approximately 1800 records), then that's what I will do.

What I am looking for is some suggestions or code examples on how best to handle this.  I'm short on time and this is new ground for me.  I have searched all over and haven't found anything that quite points me in the direction I need to go.

FWIW, this is not for a school project.

Comment: You may show us some workaround here. We won't do the all job for you.

Comment: Use a [plugin like this](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) for the browser, I would suggest trying it with fixed data first and then try to get the data with async request. The back end would just take a GET request with some text and return json data. When you get stuck then show the code you got so far (make sure your C# works correctly making the request in the browser)

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: [here](https://codepen.io/amsterdamharu/pen/jxvyyb?editors=0010) is a simple example how to use the typeahead. Please click on settings and you can see the css and js files it depends on.

Comment: HMR thank you, I am going to use the typeAhead as you suggested.  It looks like it should fit our needs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Select 2 Plugin](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) . Take a look at Ajax example. You need to get data using ajax call when user inputs 2 characters in the search box then you can remotely call the controller method to return data from DB. You need to change formatRepo and formatRepoSelection methods little bit to change display results in your search box.

HTML code:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: 'Search for a repository',
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepo(repo) {
    if (repo.loading) {
        return repo.text;
    }

    var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + repo.owner.avatar_url + "' /></div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

    if (repo.description) {
        markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.description + "</div>";
    }

    markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div></div>";

    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}
```

Controller code:

```
public class YourModel{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Value{get; set;
}

public JsonResult repositories(string searchterm){
     List<YourModel> result = //db call using search term
     return Json(result, , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, it was all very valuable to me.  We are going to try the typeAhead plug in for bootstrap 4.  Still have some things to work out with that but this is a great start.

Comment: You welcome. let me know if you need any help with typeAhead. You can even combine these two plugins together. If you feel if this answer is useful then you can select as answer. I am trying to increase my points so I can answer more questions in Stackoverflow.